# difference between "minimal" and "minimum" edge cuts.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, terminology

I was going through the topic about connectivity of graphs. There it was mentioned about the terms "*minimum edge cut*" and "*minimal edge cut*". I know both are the sets of edges if removed from the graph $G$, makes $G$ disconnected. But I am unable to catch the basic difference betwen these two terms. Is minimal always minimum or vice versa? thanks.

Comment: It is the same difference between the notion of minimal elements and minimum in a set provided by an order relation, in your case the set is the set of edge cuts and the relation in the insiemistic inclusion. In general, minimum implies minimal, the viveversa is false. Moreover minimum is uniquely determined, while in general you can have many minimal elements

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni.... thanks for timely reply..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the distinction is that a minimal example would be one that cannot be made smaller by taking a subset of the example's cuts, while a minimum is one that is as small as possible in absolute size.

For example, if we are talking about non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that add up to an even number, then $\{2\}$ is a minimum example and a minimal example, but $\{1,3\}$ is minimal but not a minimum.  There are examples which are smaller than $\{1,3\}$, but those examples are not contained in $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: thanks a lot sir. I easily grabbed it after considering your example. nice explanation.

Answer (score 13):

See, for example, [this link](http://www.theese.com/math_and_computer_science/graph_theory/edge_cuts.html), which concisely lists the definitions and the distinction, and where you'll find illustrations depicting the distinctions.

> An **edge cut** is a set of edges that, if removed from a connected graph,
>   will disconnect the graph.
>
> A **minimal edge cut** is an edge cut such that if any edge is put back in
>   the graph, the graph will be reconnected.
>
> A **minimum edge cut** is an edge cut such that there is no other edge cut
>   containing fewer edges.
>
> **A minimum edge cut is always minimal, but a minimal edge cut is not
>   always minimum** [bold face mine].
>
> A minimal (and therefore minimum) edge cut will always yield two
>   connected components.

[image] $\qquad\qquad$  [image]

[image] $\qquad\qquad$ [image]

Figure $1$ shows the original graph.

Figure $2$ shows the maximum edge cut – just remove all edges.

Figure $3$ shows a minimum (and therefore minimal) edge cut.

Figure $4$ shows a minimal edge cut (which is not minimum).

Comment: @am why... thanks sir for your timely reply. i got it now.

Comment: your explanation with Figures made it easy to understand the terms.

Comment: Yes, illustrations and/or examples always make definitions easier to understand!

Comment: @am why... sir understanding the terms with the help of figures made it easy for me to get the terms. thanks a lot.

Comment: Side-thought: using images or other forms of examples to remember definitions and distinctions is a really good strategy. Try to "link" the definitions with an "exemplar" which will help you recall how two things are relate, and how they differ.

Comment: Very nice illustration. Wowwww :-)

Comment: Fantastic answer! Keep it up @amWhy

Comment: @TannerStrunk A minimal cut always cuts into exactly two components.  Since a minimum cut is a minimal cut, minimum cuts cut into exactly two components as well.